# JSON: displaying image from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rotten-tomatoes

I've got this function to get data from rotten tomatoes api:

```
function dataHandler (data) {
     $("#title").append(" " + data.title);
     $("#studio").append(" " + data.studio);
     $("#synopsis").append(" " + data.synopsis);
     $("#poster").append(" " + data.posters.thumbnail);
};
```

It worked fine till I needed to display an image. Now it gives me only the image URL, not the image itself. Could someone explain me how to display the image correctly? Below I'm adding JSON with image URL:

```
"posters": {
        "thumbnail": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/13/43/11134356_mob.jpg",
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace your this code:

```
$("#poster").append(" " + data.posters.thumbnail);
```

with the following code:

```
$("#poster").append("<img src='"+data.posters.thumbnail+"' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#poster").append("<img src='" + data.posters.thumbnail +"' />");
```